# How to regex search strings in different order in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a script that takes in an argument and tries to find a match using regex. On single values, I don't have any issues, but when I pass multiple words, the order matters. What can I do so that the regex returns no matter what the order of the supplied words are? Here is my example script:

```
import re
from sys import argv

data = 'some things other stuff extra words'

pattern = re.compile(argv[1])
search = re.search(pattern, data)

print search
if search:
    print search.group(0)
    print data
```

So based on my example, if I pass `"some things"` as an arg, then it matches, but if i pass `"things some"`, it doesn't matches, and I would like it to. Optionally, I would like it to also return if either `"some"` or `"things"` match.

The argument passed could possibly be a regex

Comment: You could use `itertools.permutations()` to generate all possible orderings of the words in `data`, then call your regexp on each one.

Comment: @JohnGordon This was it! thanks!

Comment: why not `re.compile("|".join(argv[1:]))`? You can pass as many as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
search = filter(None, (re.search(arg, data) for arg in argv[1].split()))
```

Or

```
search = re.search('|'.join(argv[1].split()), data)
```

You can then check the search results, if `len(search) == len(argv[1].split())`, then it means all patterns matched, and `if search` is truthy, then it means at least one of them matched.

Ok, I think I got it, you can use a lookahead assertion like this:

```
>>> re.search('(?=.*thing)(?=.*same)', data)
```

You can obviously programatically build such regex:

```
re.search(''.join('(?=.*{})'.format(arg) for arg in argv[1].split()), data)
```

Comment: This would work if i was not using regex. But argv in this case could be a regex to allow for greater flexibility in the search.

Comment: I like the second option, but it still doesnt answer the question. It will match `some` or `things`, but not `things some`. It is only matching one word then, not both

Comment: perfect! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to just create several regexes and match each of them against the string. If any of them matches, you return `True`.

If you are just trying to match constant strings, the `in` operator is enough:

```
'some' in data or 'things' in data
```

Comment: I have considered that, but it quickly becomes overwhelming as the argument size grows. As in what is the arg passed is "some things other"? Then it gets too complex.

Comment: What becomes too complex? Which solution are you referring to? The `in` operator or separate regexes? You can use a loop. @securisec

Answer (score 0):

You could also just split the `data` text into sublists, and check if the ordering/reverse ordering of `search` exists in it:

```
import re

data = 'some, things other stuff extra words blah.'

search = "things, some"

def search_text(data, search):
    data_words = re.compile('\w+').findall(data)
    # ['some', 'things', 'other', 'stuff', 'extra', 'words', 'blah']
    search_words = re.compile('\w+').findall(search)
    # ['things', 'some']

    len_search = len(search_words)

    candidates = [data_words[i:i+len_search] for i in range(0, len(data_words)-1, len_search-1)]
    # [['some', 'things'], ['things', 'other'], ['other', 'stuff'], ['stuff', 'extra'], ['extra', 'words'], ['words', 'blah']]

    return search_words in candidates or search_words[::-1] in candidates

print(search_text(data, search))
```

Which Outputs:

```
True
```